# Random Forest Error Message- Response has five or fewer unique values

Tags: r, random-forest

I am attempting to use Random Forest.  The training data has 7000 observations with 12 variables.  These variables include both categorical and continuous variables.  When I submit the code I receive the following

> warning:  Warning message: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :   The
>   response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do
>   regression?

The data is structured as such:

```
CustomerId  CreditScore Geography   Gender  Age Tenure  Balance NumOfProducts   HasCrCard   IsActiveMember  EstimatedSalary Exited
15634602    619 France  Female  42  2   0   1   1   1   101348.88   1
15647311    608 Spain   Female  41  1   83807.86    1   0   1   112542.58   0
15619304    502 France  Female  42  8   159660.8    3   1   0   113931.57   1
15701354    699 France  Female  39  1   0   2   0   0   93826.63    0
15737888    850 Spain   Female  43  2   125510.82   1   1   1   79084.1 0
15574012    645 Spain   Male    44  8   113755.78   2   1   0   149756.71   1
15592531    822 France  Male    50  7   0   2   1   1   10062.8 0
15656148    376 Germany Female  29  4   115046.74   4   1   0   119346.88   1
15792365    501 France  Male    44  4   142051.07   2   0   1   74940.5 0
```

Based on research, I have attempted to change variables to factors, but this has not corrected the issue.

The random forest model code that I am using is as follows:

```
rfModel=randomForest(Exited~.,data=train)
```

I have been unable to proceed past the warning to this point.

Comment: If you want to do classification, you should convert `Exited` to a factor. Right now, I think the outcome is being treated as a continuous variable.

Comment: I used: bank_churn$Exited= as.factor(bank_churn$Exited) and still had the same issue.  I looked at NumOf Products as well because the max in that field is less than 5

Comment: Are you changing `bank_churn$Exited` before or after splitting into train and test? Try to double check that the column is being changed in the dataset you're actually running the model on. Other columns shouldn't matter, it's only the response/outcome variable.

Comment: That was absolutely correct.  I forgot to go back and redefine the train and test data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the outcome variable to a factor. For example if you the outcome variable in `train` is `y`
then run this before the model
`train$y <- as.factor(train$y)`

Comment: I tried this and got this error: 
Error in `check_outcome()`:
! For a regression model, the outcome should be `numeric`, not a `factor`.